# eBay API: Return price range for 'multivariation' listing

Tags: ebay-api

On eBay, some sellers have variations on a particular listing.  For example, a search for [flower food](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_odkw=flower+food&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR3.TRC1.A0.H0.TRS0&_nkw=flower+food&_sacat=0) often returns results with a price **range**, because the price is dependent on the number of sachets of flower food purchased.

As far as I can tell it is not straight forward to acquire this price range via the eBay API.  I have tried `GetMultipleItems`, which works, but the call takes too long, especially if you load it with multiple items.

Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: Note:  I've solved this problem by simply grouping the results of findItemsbyKeywords by ItemID and deducing the range from that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a multi-variation item, or several separate ones that are similar?

If it's the latter I don't know.... if it's the former this is easy:

Use getItem call, works a treat for me.

I have 'DetailLevel' set to  'ReturnAll' and 'IncludeItemSpecifics' set to  'true' - though I'm not sure if these are needed.

IF the item has more than one SKU, it returns like this: (this is just one variant - i removed the others but you can see what comes back...

```
<Variations>
            <Variation>
                <SKU>ESP.1255872.2420592527030</SKU>
                <StartPrice currencyID="GBP">16.0</StartPrice>
                <Quantity>11</Quantity>
                <VariationSpecifics>
                    <NameValueList>
                        <Name>Shoe Size</Name>
                        <Value>UK 3</Value>
                    </NameValueList>
                </VariationSpecifics>
                <SellingStatus>
                    <QuantitySold>1</QuantitySold>
                    <QuantitySoldByPickupInStore>0</QuantitySoldByPickupInStore>
                </SellingStatus>
                <DiscountPriceInfo>
                    <OriginalRetailPrice currencyID="GBP">22.0</OriginalRetailPrice>
                    <PricingTreatment>STP</PricingTreatment>
                    <SoldOneBay>false</SoldOneBay>
                    <SoldOffeBay>false</SoldOffeBay>
                </DiscountPriceInfo>
                <VariationProductListingDetails>
                    <EAN>5053129777792</EAN>
                </VariationProductListingDetails>
            </Variation>
</Variations>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your understanding of what I'm after is correct, but getItem is basically just a simpler version of GetMultipleItems (referred to in my question).  It might be fine for getting all the variations for _one_ ItemID, but it would probably take forever to do so for 100 items (i.e., the number that could be returned by findItemsbyKeywords).  I've solved the problem by simply grouping the results of findItemsbyKeywords by ItemID.  I presume this is how eBay do it too.